# How do I access oracle db installed on one computer from another computer with SQL developer (So that 2 people can work collaboratively on same DB)

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle19c

Hello I recently installed oracle DB and SQL developer on my PC. Now I want my friend sitting on another PC should to be able to connect and work on the same DB which is on my computer with the SQL developer. (So that we both can be connected to a single database)

Answer (score 1):

Check the DB's listener and look for specifically the IP Address, PORT , and service names you need. So in the below check on my local DB.

IP=0.0.0.0   which means all host ip addresses ( your machine's IP)

From:   `(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=0.0.0.0)(PORT=1521)))`

PORT=1521

From :   `(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=0.0.0.0)(PORT=1521)))`

SERVICE=xe

From: `Service "xe" has 1 instance(s).`

Then they can use these to connect by filling in these values in the SQL Developer Connection Dialog which has the name labels.
    $ lsnrctl status

```
LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on 15-JAN-2020 14:56:12

Copyright (c) 1991, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Start Date                15-JAN-2020 12:58:05
Uptime                    0 days 1 hr. 58 min. 6 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   /opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /opt/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/b45e40e26f79/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC1)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=0.0.0.0)(PORT=1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcps)(HOST=b45e40e26f79)(PORT=5500))(Security=(my_wallet_directory=/opt/oracle/admin/ORCL/xdb_wallet))(Presentation=HTTP)(Session=RAW))
Services Summary...
Service "8967c87908440d12e053020011ac6f8a" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "ORCL", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "ORCL" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "ORCL", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "ORCLXDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "ORCL", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "xe" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "ORCL", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
[oracle@b45e40e26f79 ~]$
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following steps?

1. Write down the IP from your PC
2. Your friend opens SQL Developer
3. Connections -> New Connection
4. Name -> Friend - Connection Type Basic
5. Hostname -> IP from your PC, Port 1521, Service Name orcl (could be XE as well)

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, you  have to have basic network connectivity between the two computers. Can your friend's computer successfully 'ping' yours?  Also, you will need to be running the oracle listener, and your database will have to be registered with it.  Check with the command line command 'lsnrctl status'.  If so, then the next step is to simply define a connection in your friend's SQL Dev, exactly like you did in yours.  Set 'connection type' to 'basic'; set 'hostname' to the network name or ip address of the computer running Oracle; set 'service name' to the name of the database.  'hostname' cannot be 'localhost', as that indicates to loop back to the originating machine.